# performance comparison when arguments are pre-known?

Tags: c++, performance

I have a function

```
enum Limit {MIN, MAX};

inline int f(pair<int, int> p, Limit l)
{
    return l == MIN ? p.first : p.second;
}
```

Compare the computatinal time of `f(p, MIN)` and `p.first`, is the first one slower even with a good compiler in release version?

Comment: So you build with optimizations enabled? Is there any difference if you hint to the compiler that the function could be make `inline`? How about `constexpr`? And what do you mean by "slower"? How have you measured? What's the difference?

Comment: If arguments are known at compile-time, then making the function `constexpr` might be a good idea.

Comment: How do you measure performance and what is the difference? f(p, MIN) includes p.first, so naturally it takes more time.

Comment: Note that `f(p, MIN)` and `p.first` are subtly different. The first is an prvalue, and the second is an lvalue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions of performance are impossible to answer through prediction. It entirely depends on what optimisations the compiler is able to make.

In this contrived case:

```
#include <utility>

enum Limit {MIN, MAX};

inline int f(std::pair<int, int> p, Limit l)
{
    return l == MIN ? p.first : p.second;
}

extern void emit(int);
int main()
{
  auto p = std::make_pair(4, 5);
  emit(f(p, MIN));
  emit(p.first);
}
```

There is no difference whatsoever:

```
main:                                   # @main
        pushq   %rax

        movl    $4, %edi
        callq   emit(int)

        movl    $4, %edi
        callq   emit(int)

        xorl    %eax, %eax
        popq    %rcx
        retq
```